# what is the correct code for changing the dimensions of the background in css?

Tags: html, css, matrix, background, frontend

I am learning working with BootStrap and in one of the exercises I have a problem with finding a CSS code.
I just want to know as you see in the photo how to fill the top right part of the page with the black background? but keep the right part of the black background slided?
and the main background is a video, how can I make it mate(not shiny)?

here is the css code and also the screenshot of what it is and what it should be:

```css
body:before {
  position         : absolute;
  box-sizing       : border-box;
  top              : 0;
  left             : 0;
  height           : 100%;
  width            : 70%;
  background-color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  opacity          : 0.95;
  transform        : matrix(1, 0, -0.158384, 1, 0, 2);
  z-index          : 1;
  content          : " ";
  display          : block;
  margin-right     : 40%;
}
```

what it is... :-/
[image: image1]

what it should be
[image: image2]

I just want to know as you see in the photo how to fill the top right part of the page with the black background? but keep the right part of the black background slided?
and the main background is a video, how can I make it mate(not shiny)?

Comment: Hey Saman, We cant see your image

Comment: Do you mean keep the top left part of the page black, rather than showing that bit of the background image?

Comment: @Nephter I just uploaded the image again, Can you see now?

Comment: @AHaworth , Yes exactly that is what I mean

Comment: so why don't you nudge the black div a little `left`?

Comment: Where is the video positioned? Is it the content of body or on another div or...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. The **real** one who delivered your readable markDown -->

Comment: my guess is, in your Transform: matrix (...) the number that is negative. maybe change it to 1 or 0 and see if that helps. let me know

Comment: also, what part are you wanting to make matte (not shiny)? the video background portion? if so, there are a few ways of doing this but id like to clarify first E>

Comment: What do you want on viewports with various aspect ratios? Is the important thing to have the black at that angle of slope or to have it those % distances from the left side at the top and the bottom?

Comment: @ITgoldman , I can not nudge it because as you see the bottom part of background is at the left end

Comment: @AHaworth , Video is a part of the body

Comment: change width to 80% and margin-right to 45%

Comment: @Nephter , I changed the numbers, but the completely change the shape of it

Comment: @Nephter , The video background portion I want to be matte

Comment: @AHaworth I want to keep the right angle but remove the left part]

Comment: @Nephter Thanks, I am in class now, I am gonna try it and be back

Comment: transform-origin: top left